# I can't connect twig with PHP Controller

Tags: php, twig

i've a problem, I'm tryna use twig in standalone project. But when i define the settings of twig, this show an error

I was reading the official document. and transfers the coding modifying a bit for adapted to my class.

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found in C:\laragon\www\mecanicos\src\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php on line 6
```

I was readed

**BaseController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use Twig_Loader_Filesystem;
use Twig\Environment;

class BaseController {
    protected $templateEngine;

    public function __construct(){
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ .'/../resources/views');
        $this->templateEngine = new Twig_Environment($loader, [
            'debug' => true,
            'cache' => false
        ]);
    }

    public function renderHTML($fileName, $data = []){
        return $this->templateEngine->render($fileName, $data);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function index(){
        
    echo $this->renderHTML('home.twig');
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/helpers.php"
        ]
    },

"require-dev": {
        "twig/twig": "9999999-dev"
    }
```

Where am i failing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a mismatch in your namespaces.
`App\Http\Controllers\BaseController` vs `App\Controllers\BaseController`
Seems Laravel cannot find the right `BaseController`. Fix the namespace and try again.

Comment: You meant `PHP` can't find the controller, OP is not even using `Laravel`

Comment: I'm not using Laravel, PHP "pure" (or vanilla).

Comment: Nonetheless, the answser still stands. `BaseController` is located in `namespace App\Controllers;`

Comment: Sorry for  answer until now, but that line was errro, i fixed, however i've the same error... I think i need the diactoros framework.